# why do I have a lot of tomcat threads in timed_waiting state

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, threadpool

In my spring boot application, I took the thread dump at different intervals and the thread remained in timed_Waiting state in all of them, where exactly are they getting blocked ? If they are in timed waiting, shouldn't they be coming out of that state at some point ?

we have set server.tomcat.threads.max as 500, No other config has been done for threads. There is no significant change in heap at the same time. However, when runnable threads increase there is a sudden dip in timed_Waiting threads and it comes back up typically to a higher level than before ([thread state, red is timed waiting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7Eva.png)). [this](https://fastthread.io/my-thread-report.jsp?p=c2hhcmVkLzIwMjMvMTEvMjMvdGhyZWFkZHVtcC5qc29uLS0zLTI4LTUz&) is the thread dump analysis.
Spring boot version - spring.boot.starter-web:2.7.5

on analyzing the dump could find most of them are tomcat nio threads, picked a few of them and followed them through dumps at different time intervals, it remained in timed_Waiting state in all of them.